# Modify selection to first element by Selection.SetElementIds

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I'm having trouble writing a script that lets med select the first element in my selection. This is useful for me because i select my correct Air Terminal from a schedule (where I can see the similar air-flow which I want to use) and use the command Create Similar from the selection. The trouble is that this command does not work when multiple elements are selected. Therefore, I want the first object from the list.
This is the code which I'm trying:

```
from Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection.Selection import SetElementIds
from System.Collections.Generic import List

uidoc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
selection = [ doc.GetElement( elId ) for elId in __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Selection.GetElementIds() ]
sel=[]
for i in selection:
    sel.append(i.Id)
uidoc.Selection.SetElementIds(List[ElementId](sel[0]))
```

That will return the following error message:

[Exception : Microsoft.Scripting.ArgumentTypeException: expected int, got ElementId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or6Qs.png)
OK, then I'll try to replace

```
uidoc.Selection.SetElementIds(List[ElementId](sel[0]))
```

with

```
uidoc.Selection.SetElementIds(List[ElementId](sel[0].IntegerValue))
```

[This seems to work, but selection is not modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nR8z.png)

I am just starting to write RPS-scripts, but I'm hoping someone will show me what am I doing wrong here even if it is very obvious.

Thank you.
Kyrre

EDIT:
Thank you Jeremy, for solving this for me! The trick was to generate a List, not a python list. .Add method is what I did not get.

Final code if someone is interested:

```
from Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection.Selection import SetElementIds
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import ElementId
uidoc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
selection = [ doc.GetElement( elId ) for elId in __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Selection.GetElementIds() ]
sel=[]
for i in selection:
    sel.append(i.Id)
ids=List[ElementId](1)
ids.Add(sel[0]) 
uidoc.Selection.SetElementIds(ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetElementIds` takes a .NET `ICollection<ElementId>` argument, as you can see from the [Revit API documentation](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/cf8c11bb-f0c7-6d50-cbdf-41d0a010d9d6.htm).

Your statement calls the .NET `List` constructor that expects an integrer argument specifying the number `N` of elements to allovate space for:  `List[ElementId](N)`.

`sel[0]` is an `ElementId`, not an integer, which causes the first error.

`sel[0].IntegerValue` is a (very large and semi-arbitrary) integer number, so that causes no error. However, you are still leaving the `List` empty, unpopulated.

You should initialise the `List` for one single element and add that:

```
ids = List[ElementId](1)
ids.Add(sel[0])
```